# Custom post_type search pages

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, search

So I have a section on my site that specifically searches a custom post type for YouTube videos. I'm absolutely able to search the custom type. However, I'm unsure how to create a search page that has custom formatting geared toward this type of search.

I've created a custom loop-youtube.php and modified within search.php `get_template_part( 'loop');` to `get_template_part( 'loop', 'youtube');` however, it affects the search results globally.

Is there a way to create a custom search.php page for a specific post_type?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you restricting the search to your custom post type? If you are doing it by passing an additional argument, i.e. &type=myCustomPostType, you could use a conditional test, like:

```
if(isset($_GET['type'] && $_GET['type'] == 'myCustomPostType')):
  get_template_part('loop','youtube');
else:
 get_template_part(loop);
endif;
```

Comment: I added a search filter in functions.php then I added a hidden query to the form         
`<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="youtube" />`
to the form.

Comment: Then change what i did above to only test for `$_GET['post_type'] == 'youtube'` and i think that should do it. Now, I'm also assuming that you're either using a dedicated form just for searching youtube post types or doing some kind of test before applying the search filter. If not that filter will also affect search results globally.

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error on the first line..I fixed the semi colon at the end..still getting the same error. `if(isset($_GET['type'] && $_GET['post_type'] == 'youtube'));`

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'youtube'):` I didn't close the `isset` function. The colon should be a colon, not a semicolon. It works just like the brackets `if{ } else { }` do.

Answer (score 1):

I have my search page split up like this:

```
<?php if ($wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post') { 
 // output for posts format
} else {
 // output for other formats
} ?>
```

I think query_vars is more efficient than $_GET in this case.